# run bash commands inside docker container after entrypoint command has finished (which starts a server)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose script and I would like to run some bash commands after the container has started.

The entrypoint for the container is a script that starts a webserver. So my bash commands would have to be executed once the server is ready to take requests.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs, you can use exec to run command in an existing container:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/exec/

You just run docker-compose exec with the name of the service:

```
docker-compose exec cbd bash
```

Or any executable in the container. Of course, this requires that bash is installed in the container.

Answer (score 0):

I run a script (.sh) which after the command *docker-compose up -d* run a command into the container like

```
#/bin/bash
cd /myDockerComposePath
docker-compose up -d
docker exec mycontainer bash -c "/mylocation/myscript.sh"
```

alternative for the last line, or if you need to run more commands

```
docker exec mycontainer bash -c "myCommand"
```